# Postman: Create complex MULTIPART_FORM_DATA request

Tags: spring, spring-boot, postman

I need to create a request using postman. The spring boot endpoint is:

```
@RequestMapping(
    value = "/group",
    method = RequestMethod.POST,
    consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE
)
public ResponseEntity<String> group(
    @RequestPart("items") List<ItemType> items,
    @RequestPart("group") GroupType group);
```

where:

```
public class ItemType {
  private String description;
  private String security;
  private Date bestdate;
  private MultipartFile content;
}

public class GroupType {
  private String description;
  private String security;
  private String metadata;
}
```

As you can see, `ItemType` contains an `MultiPartFile`.

I mean, what do I need to write on `"items"` and `"group"` parts:

[image]

Comment: What is the issue you facing while creating !!!

Comment: I've edited post.

Comment: if you are send request using json then  multipart is not working

Answer (score 0):

There is a option in Postman to provide the form data, where you can pass both the text and file.

The json part of the body should also be set as "File" rather then "Text", and put your json data in a json file for example "a.json".
Check below , Hope this will help.
[image]